# Solve differential equation, method unclear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assuming I have a voltage $U(t)=500\cdot\sin(2\cdot\pi\cdot f\cdot t)$ and $C$ as a constant value (let's say $10$ nF), I have to solve the following equation using the differential method, how do I do it?

$$ I(t[k, k+1]) = C(t[k, k+1])\cdot\frac{U(t[k+1])-U(t[k])}{t[k+1]-t[k]}
$$

I solved $\frac{U(t[k+1])-U(t[k])}{t[k+1]-t[k]}$ numerically and can simply multiply $C$ into the formula, which gives me a sinusoidal waveform for the current $I(t)$. 
My question is, what does $I(t[k, k+1])$ do here?
I've read about the euler's method (forward difference) but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with my question here.

I would appreciate any tips and help on solving this.

Comment: As $Q = C U$ we have $\frac{dQ}{dt} = I = C \frac{dU}{dt}$.

Comment: Sorry, i might have been unclear with my problem. Yes @Cesareo the equation I have in my question is based on I = C*dU/dt, however I have to build a mathematical model based on the differential method, hence the indexes [k+1], [k]. I'm just unsure how to solve the current using "differential" in this case.